# Convenient and simple solution to receive and answer emails in a small Django app

Tags: django, email

I am developing a Django app which uses Email in some of its components (but not at its core). I am looking for a simple and cheap solution that satisfies the following requirements:

- Only the custom domain of the app is used (no `username@gmail` address)
- Django can send emails programmatically (error reporting, user data from forms)
- The admin can receive and and answer mails through an email client of their choice
- The provider should allow sending mass emails (not a priority)
- The solution does not need to be free

Solutions I have considered so far:

- Using my hosting provider: They understandably don't support custom email accounts for VPS customers
- Amazon SES: would work for sending email, but received emails would land in a S3 bucket; it is unclear to me how to connect this to an email client
- Sendgrid: would work for sending email, but the only way to handle inbound mail is to forward it as HTTP POST request to a view
- Django extensions to read and send email through the admin interface: I can't use my email client
- Google Workspace: seems like this could work. My issue is that it includes a lot of functionality I don't really need. Does anyone have experience with this?

All I really need is to alias a standard email account to my custom domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom domain email account with any provider that supports SMTP clients (including Google Wspace) and configure the SMTP credentials into Django's email backend (or use a fancier email package, like for exmaple Django-Anymail).

in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.email_provider_server.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email_account_user_name'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'secret_password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Receive emails and reply through the provider's webmail or configure IMAP/SMTP in a desktop client like Outlook/Thunderbird/WindowsMail etc.

The provider will give you the IMAP/SMTP settings. Best practice is to feed the password into Django's settings.py through environment variables etc. for security.

Comment: With your help, l understood why I got stuck. I was not aware there was such a thing as an email hosting provider. I wrongly equated email providers with the end user focused free email services I have used until now. But they are not suited for my problem. Now I can look for a proper service. Can somebody recommend one they have had good experience with? I want to avoid subscribing to Google Workspace since I will not be using any of the other components. Btw, thanks for pointing me to `django-anymail`, I may use it in the future.

Comment: Most web hosting providers that are based on CPanel etc. offer free email accounts if you have your domain hosted with them.

Comment: Personally I would go with Google, for reliability and deliverability purposes. Not all providers offer the DKIM functionality and many of the smaller ones have their IP addresses black listed which means your sent email may end up in peoples' spam folder.

Comment: I did some research and decided to go with Workspace. Thank you for your help! Much appreciated.